# Splitting a csv file into multiple files

Tags: csv, split

I have a csv file of 150500 rows and I want to split it into multiple files containing 500 rows (entries)

I'm using Jupyter and I know how to open and read the file. However, I don't know how to specify an output_path to record the newly created files from splitting the big one.

I have found this code online but once again since I don't know what is my output_path I don't know how to use it. Moreover, for this block of code I don't understand how we specify the input file.

```py
import os

def split(filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=1000,
          output_name_template='output_%s.csv', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=delimiter)
    current_piece = 1
    current_out_path = os.path.join(
        output_path,
        output_name_template % current_piece
    )
    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=delimiter)
    current_limit = row_limit
    if keep_headers:
        headers = reader.next()
        current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i + 1 > current_limit:
            current_piece += 1
            current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
            current_out_path = os.path.join(
                output_path,
                output_name_template % current_piece
            )
            current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=delimiter)
            if keep_headers:
                current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        current_out_writer.writerow(row)
```

My file name is DataSet2.csv and it's in the same file in jupyter as my ipynb notebook is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_small_files = 301
lines_per_small_file = 500

largeFile = open('large.csv', 'r')
header = largeFile.readline()

for i in range(number_of_small_files):
    smallFile = open(str(i) + '_small.csv', 'w')

    smallFile.write(header) # This line copies the header to all small files

    for x in range(lines_per_small_file):
        line = largeFile.readline()
        smallFile.write(line)

    smallFile.close()

largeFile.close()
```

This will create many small files in the same directory. About 301 of them. They will be named from `0_small.csv` to `300_small.csv`.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to be related to splitting rows. Filehandler is the return value of open(). You send that as the first argument to your code. But again, that isn't for splitting by rows.

I didn't test it, but this code should split the file into multiple files. I'm off to sleep now, but I'll check again tomorrow to see if you have any problems.

Comment: with open('DataSet2.csv', "r") as inputFile:
    for i in range(int(150500/500)):
        with open(str(i) + "_small.csv", "w") as outputFile:
            lines = inputFile.readlines(500)
            outputFile.write(str(lines))

Comment: This code indeed created 300 small files, however, it saves them in a single row. How can I alter it so that it adds every new row under the previous one? Also how can I skip the very first row in my large.csv file, cause that row belongs to the headers and it's offsetting the 500 data points that I want to have in every small file? Thank you so much for your help really appreciate it!

Comment: Also my apologies, the file has  150500 excluding the headers. So with the headers I have 150501 rows, in which I want to skip reading the very first (header) row.

Comment: My answer was actually wrong. readline(n) reads n characters, not n lines. I edited my answer. This should properly write all lines in separate rows. This also copies the header to all small files. To stop that, remove the smallFile.write(header) line.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard unix utilities:

```
cat DataSet2.csv | tail -n +2 | split -l 500 --additional-suffix=.csv output_
```

This pipeline takes the original file, strips off the first line with 'tail -n +2', and then splits the rest into 500 line chunks that are put into files with names that start with 'output_' and end with '.csv'